# Ubuntu map CIFS / SMB share using active domain credentials without password file

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory, server-message-block, cifs, fstab

Is there a way in Ubuntu 18.04 to map an SMB share when the users login without using a password file?  The boxes I have are members of a Windows Active Directory domain and the users will use their domain credentials to authenticate.  I want to automatically map drives for users and have the login be essentially passed from the user context like it is in Windows.  I know there is the FSTAB and a way to use a password file for that, but I want to avoid making the users update that file when they change their domain password if possible.

Answer (score 3):

Try to avoid cached passwords. Linux clients are capable of using proper Kerberos.

[Configure sssd with with the ad provider.](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-sssd)

Add [pam_mount](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/pam_mount.8.html), and configure it in [/etc/security/pam_mount.conf.xml](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/pam_mount.conf.5.html). cifs mounts in here should specific options, probably including `options="sec=krb5i,vers=3.0"`, for Kerberos and a modern version of SMB that is not disabled like SMB1 should be. ([Thanks Arch wiki.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pam_mount))