# How to mount CIFS shares in Linux without password, using domain credentials?

Tags: ubuntu, centos, cifs, sssd

I have Ubuntu 18.04 and CentOS 7 boxes, they are members of Windows domain (using sssd).
Linux users need to mount CIFS shares from domains fileservers. What should be done in order to provide passwordless mount, using Kerberos?
(I see a similar question, unfortunately without accepted answer [Ubuntu map CIFS / SMB share using active domain credentials without password file](https://serverfault.com/questions/940445/ubuntu-map-cifs-smb-share-using-active-domain-credentials-without-password-fil))

Answer (score 0):

Done, using pam_mount (Ubuntu18.04, part of MS Windows domain based on sssd):

- apt install keyutils libpam-mount
- Added to /etc/security/pam_mount.conf.xml